# C# - Finding key in an array by the value of its complex structure

Tags: c#, arrays, key

is there a method in C# to find the key of the item in an array by its "subvalue"? Some hypothetical function "`findKeyofCorrespondingItem()`"?

```
struct Items
{
 public string itemId;
 public string itemName;
}

 int len = 18;
 Items[] items = new Items[len];

items[0].itemId = "684656"; 
items[1].itemId = "411666"; 
items[2].itemId = "125487"; 
items[3].itemId = "756562"; 
// ...
items[17].itemId = "256569"; 

int key = findKeyofCorrespondingItem(items,itemId,"125487"); // returns 2
```

Comment: `items[0] = "684656";` is illegal, since `"684656"` is a `string`, and `items[0]` is an `Items`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the ".itemId". Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.FindIndex. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System.Linq
...
Array.FindIndex(items, (e) => e.itemId == "125487"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my question cause I forgot something. Now it is completely different problem.

Comment: This wors for me: Array.FindIndex(items, (e) => e.itemId == "125487"))

Comment: Tnx a lot, I had to finish other stuff to make this work. But it is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int findKeyofCorrespondingItem(Items[] items, string searchValue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].itemId == searchValue)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

You can run a loop and check if itemId equal to the value you are searching for. Return -1 if no item matches with value.

Solution with Linq:

```
public static int findKeyofCorrespondingItem(Items[] items, string searchValue)
{
    return Array.FindIndex(items, (e) => e.itemId == searchValue);
}
```

Comment: I wanted to give you simple solution